# copy objects from one scene to another

Tags: python, scripting, customization, layers, viewlayers

I opened a blend, and I created 2 scenes.
in the 1st I have a box and in the 2nd. I have a door.
save my file and then use the command duplicate window of the information bar in the window tab.
in each window place a scene, as you can see in one is the door and in another is the box.

My question is the following and consists of three parts!

How can you copy objects from one scene to another?
Can you simply pass an object from one scene to another as you usually do when you move an object from one layer to another layer?
Is there any way to do this?
[image: Image Reference]

Answer (score 4):

The the *Make Links* operator to link objects between scenes.

Select a bunch of objects, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *Make Links > To Scene* then pick a scene from the list.

Beware that without further action these linked objects remain linked and are in fact one and the same, that means any transformations made in one scene will propagate to others both in *Object Mode* and in *Edit Mode*.

To make them independent select them and press <kbd>U</kbd> *Make Single User* then choose an option. *Object* will make them move independently but still share *Object Data* or geometry. *Object & Data* will make them unique and completely independent.

[image]

For 2.8 series this can be found under the 3D View header menu, either under *Object > Relations > Make Single User*, or *Object > Make Links*.

Comment: thanks, I thought they were going to slap me for asking things like that hahahaha, but I see that if it was worth it it solves a lot of problems and it will help me to accelerate my project,
Thank you so much...!

Comment: Could you update this for current Blender version please? `U` doesn't do anything anymore

Comment: oops, found it under Object > Relations

Comment: Done, updated for 2.8+

Answer (score 2):

**API methods**

Code to link the context object of context scene "Scene" to another scene named "Scene.001"

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data
```

in 2.8

```
>>> C.scene
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
>> D.scenes['Scene.001'].collection.objects.link(C.object)
```

2.5x to 2.7x

```
>>> C.scene
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
>> D.scenes['Scene.001'].objects.link(C.object)
```

Comment: thank you, 2.7 is for me thanks a lot